# Publication process in the Communications of the ACM

Tags: journals, journal-workflow, acm

Does anybody have experience publishing at the [Communications of the ACM?](http://cacm.acm.org/) I couldn't find any information about average duration of the review cycle or acceptance rates.

Comment: CACM isn't really a normal journal: it's sort of a magazine and sort of a journal.  If you want specific figures like that, it really depends on what you're talking about and how it links with their editorial plans and schedule.  In short: you need to talk to the editors to find out the information that you need.

Comment: How is this question opinion-based? It's asking for facts about the journal, not interpretations of these facts.